# Subscribe to EventEmitter in Angular2 not working

Tags: javascript, angular, eventemitter

I'm learning Angular 2. I'm trying to send data from a component to other on the click of the first one.

Both components are siblings.

This is my code so far:

#### First Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'jsonTextInput',
  templateUrl: '../templates/jsonTextInput.html',
  directives: [Card, CardTitle, CardDescription, Icon],
  providers: [JsonChangeService]
})

export class JsonTextInput {
  json: string = '';

  constructor (private jsonChangeService: JsonChangeService) {
    this.jsonChangeService = jsonChangeService
  }

  process () {
      this.jsonChangeService.jsonChange(this.json)
  }
}
```

#### This is the service:

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()

export default class JsonChangeService {
  public jsonObject: Object;

  stateChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor (){
    this.jsonObject = {};
  }

  jsonChange (obj) {
    console.log('sending', obj)
    this.jsonObject = obj
    this.stateChange.emit(this.jsonObject)
  }
}
```

The call from the first component to the service is working, since the `sending` is being printed.

#### This is the second Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'jsonRendered',
  templateUrl: '../templates/jsonrendered.html',
  directives: [Card, CardTitle],
  providers: [JsonChangeService]
})

export class JsonRendered {
  private jsonObject: Object

  constructor (private jsonChangeService: JsonChangeService) {
    this.jsonChangeService = jsonChangeService
    this.jsonObject = jsonChangeService.jsonObject
    this.jsonChangeService.stateChange.subscribe(json => { this.jsonObject = json; console.log('Change made!') })
  }

  ngOnInit () {
    console.log(1)
  }

  ngOnChanges () {
    console.log(2)
  }

  renderJson () {
    console.log(3)
  }
}
```

The function inside the subscribe to stateChange never runs. What am I missing?

### EDIT

This is the content of my `stateChange` EventEmitter:

```
_isAsync: true
_isScalar: false
destination: undefined
dispatching: false
hasCompleted: false
hasErrored: false
isStopped: false
isUnsubscribed: false
observers: Array[0]
source:undefined
```

Comment: does the call to `this.stateChange.next` actually emits the event?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: can you not simply call `this.stateChange.emit`?

Comment: I have changed `next` to `emit` It still not working. I have updated my question with the change

Comment: I also had added the content of the stateChange content

Comment: and in your `jsonrendered.html`, you have something like `(stateChange)="someHandler($event)"`?

Comment: On the `jsonTextInput.html` which is the one that calls the emitter I have this:
`<icon (click)='process()' name='tick'></icon>` process is the one that calls the EventEmitter

Comment: I just need to run a method when the content of the `stateChange` has changed, inside the other class

Comment: perhaps the injection as a service is throwing me off...normally i would declare it this way `@Output() stateChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();` and handle it ion the other end with the `(stateChange)=...` snippet i commented above

Comment: could you paste an example of how would you do that as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two different instances of `JsonChangeService`. That's why you don't receive message between components. You need to have one instance service, i.e. on parent component or on top level like this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [JsonChangeService])
```

Comment: I have that on my main.ts that imports the AppComponent. But still not working

Comment: The recommendation in the Angular2 documentation is to have it on the `AppComponent`, not in the bootstrap unless absolutely neccecary. See 'Configuring the injector' [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

Comment: Do you remove providers from each components?

Comment: @Pablo Remove the service from the `providers` section of any "sub-components".