# Error routing with a pattern on Angular 2 (specific angular 2.1.0)

Tags: angular

I am developing an app, and I need have login and app, the app have a common navigator tha will be  used for all routes of app, but I have some problems with routes.

```
export const routes = RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: "login", component: LoginComponent},
  {path: "", component: HomeComponent, children: [
    {path: "history", component: HmodeComponent},
    {path: "realtime", component: RtmodeComponent}
  ]},
]);
```

My components are

Nav (navigation component for app)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

 }
```

Login component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Home component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Hmode component

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-hmode',
      templateUrl: './hmode.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./hmode.component.css']
    })
    export class HmodeComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

}
```

And I want make login, and when login is correct redirect to app, my idea is use home component to contain all routes

These are the views (html)

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

login.component.html

```
<p>
  login works!
</p>
```

home.component.html

```
<div class="main-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-nav></app-nav>
```

hmode.component.html

```
<p> Home content </p>
```

And nav.html is another component, and I want that after login redirect to ***hmode*** and that navbar is ever visible for all routes, for that reason I am using hom component.

Answer (score 0):

I did a solution for this that I described in this post:
[Angular 2 - Content not loading in router outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767142/angular-2-content-not-loading-in-router-outlet/40768288?noredirect=1#comment68789801_40768288)

There's a similar solution that you can check out here:
it looks like they are using an *ngIf with an authservice to display different routes based on the values of the LoggedIn function:
https://github.com/predatorkill/ng2-forms-demo

Comment: Thanks, this is a base to solve my problem, using this another source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500698/subscribe-to-eventemitter-in-angular2-not-working

The solution was almost what you wrote, only there is one difference, we must add the GlobalEventsManager to app.module as a provider and when you use it only import it and doesn't use it as provider on individual component only on app.module. The reason is that can't be different instances of GlobalEventsManager.

Thanks